# How can one explore Helgen (before its destruction)

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, xbox-360

Is it possible to explore Helgen without it being destroyed, without the use of mods?

Comment: What version? Console or PC?

Comment: @Oak, you edited that piece of information out of the original question with your editing.

Answer (score 4):

If you're playing on Windows, you can use a console command to explore Helgen. I'm not aware of a way to do this on consoles, short of transferring a saved game from Windows to your console.

In a PC copy of Skyrim, go to the Skyrim main menu and open the console with the <kbd>~</kbd> key. (If you have a game loaded already, Helgen will already be destroyed and this won't work.) Then enter this command:

```
coc HelgenExterior02
```

That places you just inside the gate that you go through on the carriage when starting the game as a prisoner. Several NPCs will be standing around or fighting, but they'll leave you alone. The only buildings you'll be able to enter are [Helgen Keep](http://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Helgen_Keep) and [Helgen Homestead](http://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Helgen_Homestead).

The gates leading out of the city will be locked, saying they require a key to open. If you want to open them, open the console, click on the gate, and type `unlock`.

This probably completely screws up the main quest of the game, so once you're done exploring, I suggest exiting the game.

Comment: I don't know how to transfer saved games from Windows to XBox 360, but I could provide a saved game in Helgen before it's destroyed if that would help.